# About betting out of turn, action reverting to original players,

Tags: rules

Sio, 6 handed PLO game, 1-2, button straddle for 15.  Only four players present.  SB, BB, UTG, and Button.  Button straddles 15, blinds are chatting, UTG calls 15 while blinds are chatting away.  I tell UTG, sorry action is over here at SB.  Action reverts.  Small blind folds, BB calls 15, UTG raises to 50.  Can he or is he restricted from doing so?

Comment: It depends on the rule set you are following.

Answer (score 3):

Action out of turn is binding as long as the action is still valid. Which in this case means UTG gun has committed to calling 15 when he called 15 out of turn, as long as 15 is still the valid action.

If the action was other then calling 15 when it got to UTG, because somebody raises than the UTG player goes back to square one were he can call the raise, raise or fold.

Comment: Yes, this is a common angle shot. I have kicked players out of the game for doing this intentionally.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I have had floor people over a number of times for this particular rule, and surprisingly they drop the ball on this one almost as much as they get it right.